# Obtener solo los dias entre dos fechas

Tags: php

Tengo un script en cual me lista los dias entre dos fechas. Lo que necesito es solo los dias y no el mes ni el año.

```
<?php
$fecha1 = "2019-03-01";
$fecha2 = "2019-03-12";

for($i=$fecha1;$i<=$fecha2;$i = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i ."+ 1 days"))){
    echo $i . "<br />";
}
?>

//El resultado de este script es:

2019-03-01
2019-03-02
2019-03-03
2019-03-04
2019-03-05
2019-03-06
2019-03-07
2019-03-08
2019-03-09
2019-03-10
2019-03-11
2019-03-12
```

Pero necesito que sea:

```
01
02
03...
```

Cada cambio que hago me da un error, no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de este modo

```
<?php

$fecha1 = "2019-03-01";
$fecha2 = "2019-03-12";

for($i=$fecha1;$i<=$fecha2;$i = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i ."+ 1 days"))){
    $data = explode("-", $i);
    echo $data[2];
}
```

Resultado

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
```

**ACLARACIONES**

- Haré uso de la función `explode` para descomponer en varias partes la cadena principal que contiene la variable `$i`
- La función `explode` necesita como primer argumento el símbolo por el cual descompondré en múltiples partes la string original; para este caso usaremos el símbolo de `-`
- Declaro una función llamada `data` donde por medio de la función `explode` almacenaré el valor de cada posición, como ahora es un array de posiciones podré tomar solo la parte que necesite indicando por el número en que lugar se encuentra, en este caso es la posición [2]

**La función `EXPLODE`**

> Divide a un string en varios strings

[Fuente Oficial para consulta](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)

**Extras**

Si quieres de hecho comprobar el tipo de dato que ahora almacena la variable `$data` puedes hacerlo a través de la función `gettype()` del modo siguiente

```
echo gettype($data);
```

Obteniendo un resultado como este

> array

Incluso si le haces un `var_dump()` a dicho elemento así

```
var_dump($data);
```

Verás algo como lo siguiente en tu pantalla o consola

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "2019" [1]=> string(2) "03" [2]=> string(2) "12" }
```

Comment: La verdad no sabia como hacer, me estaba volviendo loco. Ni mucho menos se me ocurrio usar `explode`. Muchas gracias por compartir tus conocimientos @alfa-p

Comment: Perdon, como lo puedo pasar usando `while`?

Answer (score 3):

Otra manera de hacerlo sería trabajando con objetos del tipo [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php). La ventaja es que se crearían verdaderos objetos que pueden ser utilizados en contextos diferentes y para presentar los datos se aplicarían métodos propios de dichos objetos aportando versatilidad y reusabilidad al código.

Por ejemplo en este caso, crearíamos dos objetos `DateTime` a partir de las fechas y luego un objeto del tipo [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateperiod.php) del cual se puede extraer el día (que es lo que necesitas), pero si se quisiera otra cosa, también se podría extraer usando el mismo objeto, porque por cada item (`$mDate`) del bucle obtienes un verdadero objeto `DateTime` con todas sus propiedades y métodos.

El código sería este:

```
<?php
    $startDate=new DateTime('2019-03-01');
    $endDate=new DateTime('2019-03-12');
    # Aumentamos un día a la fecha final para que ésta sea incluida en el perído
    $endDate = $endDate->modify( '+1 day' ); 
    $mInterval=new DateInterval('P1D');
    $mPeriod = new DatePeriod($startDate,$mInterval,$endDate);

    foreach ($mPeriod as $mDate){
        echo $mDate->format('d').PHP_EOL;
    }
?>
```

**Salida:**

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
```

Si haces un `var_dump` de cualquier objeto `$mDate` del bucle, tendrías esto, que es un verdadero objeto `DateTime` con toda la potencialidad que se puede aprovechar de los objetos:

```
object(DateTime)#6 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-03-01 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

---

### Demostración

Aquí te dejo un <kbd>**[DEMOSTRACIÓN](https://rextester.com/RHEZH77882)**</kbd> en línea, donde podrás hacer pruebas sobre el código.

Comment: Voy a tenerlo en cuenta. Con `for` tenia problemas con el diseño, tome lo aprendido para poder solucionar eso. Muchas gracias @a-cedano

Answer (score -1):

Simplemente recoge el día de la fecha con:

```
date('d', strtotime($i))
```

Comment: ¿Y me explicas por qué eso funciona y cómo funciona?