# rango de fechas inicio y final en php

Tags: php, laravel, bucle-for, foreach, tablas

como realizar una linea de tiempo según el rango de fechas inicio y fin desarrolladas con tabla se realizo un ciclo for para ese medio pero tengo también

```
$fechainicio = '19-03-2019';
$fechafin = '19-04-2019';

for($i=$fechainicio;$i<=$fechafin;$i++){
  echo $i;
}
```

pero tengo un problema  al momento de colocarlo en esta tabla no me funciona como quiero coloco el ciclo correcto pero cuando intento colocarle el color correspondiente me genera pero un ciclo totalmente diferente le agradezco el que me pueda ayudar a solucionar este problema o lo tengo que hacer con un componente muchas gracias.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
        <th>Etapa</th>
        <th>Actividad</th> 
        <th>Producto</th>
        <th>Departamento</th>
        <th>Analistas</th>
        <th>Tareas</th>
        <th>Tipo de Tarea</th>
        <th>%</th>
        <th>Municipio</th>
        <th>Gestores</th>
            <th>Beneficiarios</th>
            <th>Enero</th>
            <th>Febrero</th>
            <th>Marzo</th>
            <th>Abril</th>
            <th>Mayo</th>
            <th>Junio</th>
            <th>Julio</th>
            <th>Agosto</th>
            <th>Septiembre</th>
            <th>Octubre</th>
            <th>Noviembre</th>
            <th>Diciembre</th>          
      </tr>
        @foreach($tasks as $task)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$task->product->activity->phase->name}}</td> 
                <td>{{$task->product->activity->name}}</td> 
                <td>{{$task->product->name}}</td> 
                <td>{{$task->product->department->name}}</td> 
                <td>
                    @include('report.partials.analistas')
                </td>
                <td>{{$task->name}}</td> 
                <td>
                     {{ ($task->type_task == 0 ? 'Individual': '') }}
                     {{ ($task->type_task == 1 ? 'Grupal': '') }}
                     {{ ($task->type_task  == 2 ? 'Transversal': '') }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="badge {{ ($task->done < 60 ? 'bg-red' : ( $task->done < 99 ? 'bg-yellow' : 'bg-green' ) ) }}">
                        {{ number_format($task->done) }} % 
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{$task->city->name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    @include('report.partials.gestores')
                </td>
                <td>
                    @include('report.partials.beneficiarios')
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{$project->date_initial}}
                    </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Para recorrer un rango de fechas puedes utilizar las clases [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php), [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php) y [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateperiod.php) de php

```
$comienzo = new DateTime('19-03-2019');
$final = new DateTime('19-04-2019');
// Necesitamos modificar la fecha final en 1 día para que aparezca en el bucle
$final = $final->modify('+1 day');

$intervalo = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$periodo = new DatePeriod($comienzo, $intervalo, $final);

foreach ($periodo as $dt) {
    echo $dt->format("Y-m-d\n");
}
```

```
// Resultado:
2019-03-19
2019-03-20
2019-03-21
// ...
2019-04-17
2019-04-18
2019-04-19
```

Otra opción, algo más corta, pero con el mismo output, es:

```
$comienzo = new DateTime('19-03-2019');
$final = new DateTime('19-04-2019');

for($i = $comienzo; $i <= $final; $i->modify('+1 day')){
    echo $i->format("Y-m-d") . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Pero hay un problema aquí y es que la fecha final no se incluye en el intervalo (el día 20 de abril no aparece en este caso). Para incluirlo hay que modificar la fecha final agregándole un día. Habría que hacer algo como: `$final = $final->modify( '+1 day' );`  [Ver un ejemplo en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/246446/29967).

Comment: Sí, pero en estos ejemplos en ambos casos el bucle va de 19 a 19 (esto es lo que creo que el OP quiere). Por eso puse `$final = new DateTime('20-04-2019');` en el primer ejemplo (el 20 no sale).

Comment: Entiendo, pero esto es problemático. Se supone que él recibirá este dato como fecha final: `19-04-2019`, la forma automática de aumentar un día es modificando la fecha. No puedes cambiarlo de forma arbitraría en el código a `20-04-2019` para crear el objeto a partir de esa cadena cambiada *a mano*.

Comment: Entiendo, tienes toda la razón, respuesta editada

Comment: si para decir cuando mando ciclo for me recorra como lo tengo en la tabla y me pinte color rojo según  la fecha enero o febrero  y así

Comment: @A.Cedano entiendo lo se va realizar pero recorrido lo q hace es colocarme el array con todos los datos asta esa fecha pero lo tengo es digamos enero y febrero y pintalo en esa fecha digamos un evento inicia 20/03/2019 y acaba 20/04/2019 y en etiqueta html mostra como lo muestra fullcalendar pero solo realizado en php